# How to display only the relevant values of x on a logarithmic scale?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like the logarithmic scale to display only the relevant x values in decimal and not powers of 10.

Do you have any idea how I can do this?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = sorted([0.09, 20, 0.6, 6, 0.05, 0.5, 0.4, 4, 0.3, 3, 2, 0.1, 0.2,
            0.9, 0.8, 10, 0.7, 1, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.005])
y = list(np.arange(0.0, 2.6, 0.1))

data = {'x': x,
        'y': y}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.plot(x='x')
plt.ylim(0, max(y)+0.5)
plt.xscale('log', base=10)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What are *relevant x values*?

Comment: Values of the x list: `0.09, 20, 0.6, 6, 0.05, 0.5, 0.4, 4, 0.3, 3, 2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.9, 0.8, 10, 0.7, 1, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.005` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ScalerFormatter`:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.set_xticks(x)
```

[image: ScalarFormatter]

Comment: Thank you and if I want to see only the values of the x list `0.09, 20, 0.6, 6, 0.05, 0.5, 0.4, 4, 0.3, 3, 2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.9, 0.8, 10, 0.7, 1, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0.005`? Not 0.0, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0 .

Comment: thanks it works fine, but isn't there a way to display only the values of the x list? On your graph some values overlap on the x-axis and it's not very readable.

Comment: There are only the values of x on the graph (26). The values overlap because you are using a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Oh indeed thank you! A solution (besides changing the size with `plt.xticks(fontsize=..)`)would be to round(.., 1) the values of x from 0.1 to 0.9 and int() value from 1 to 20, but I can't do it. Do you have an idea how do this?